# Распарсить и распечать период в формате ISO8601

Tags: java, kotlin, jodatime

Я хочу такую строку распарсить P3Y6M4DT12H30M17S(ОДин из форматов)  и распечатать 3 года 6 месяцев 4 суток 12 часов 30 минут и 17 секунды

в JodaTime есть ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P3W") этот класс явно делает что-то близкое к тому, что мне надо

`public static PeriodFormatter standard() {
        if (cStandard == null) {
            cStandard = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLiteral("P")
                .appendYears()
                .appendSuffix("Y")
                .appendMonths()
                .appendSuffix("M")
                .appendWeeks()
                .appendSuffix("W")
                .appendDays()
                .appendSuffix("D")
                .appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter("T")
                .appendHours()
                .appendSuffix("H")
                .appendMinutes()
                .appendSuffix("M")
                .appendSecondsWithOptionalMillis()
                .appendSuffix("S")
                .toFormatter();
        }
        return cStandard;
    }`

Но я никак не могу распечатать, то что он делает. Никакие toString не помогают, так же есть метод duration, пробую его распечатать и тоже фигня какая то.

Comment: Это то что ищете? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440795/5479247

Comment: Ну я смотрел это тоже, с утра более менее разобрался. Этот способ PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.getDefault()).print(ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P3W"))   Выдает мне все по стандарту, но я хотел PeriodFormatterBuilder() использовать, как в выбранном ответе по вашей ссылке, но у него почему-то нет того метода print, который они вызывают в вопросе, что странно..

Comment: Ааа..увидел, они там toFormatter у билдера вызывают.. спасибо